# Arduino voltage check

Tags: arduino

I have a program that checks if a voltage on an analog pin falls below a set voltage (3V), and if it does it prints a number on serial after waiting for 3 minutes.

```
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  // Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) to a voltage (0 - 5V):
  float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
  // print out the value you read:
  if(voltage < 3.00) {
    delay(180000);
    Serial.println("8");
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, if the voltage goes up (>= 3V) before 3 minutes it should not print the number on serial. How to do this?

Comment: This could be different on different types f arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch from an imperative, sequential code to a more event based approach. Keep track of the last time you've seen the voltage stay above the threshold while keeping on looping; when the time elapsed is greater than 3 minutes, print the value and reset the timer (to avoid printing at each iteration onwards).

BTW, your code can be more efficient (not that here it matters anyway) if you avoid floating point conversion (which on Arduino is entirely emulated in software) and just compare with the correct integer value.

```
unsigned long last_good = 0;
const int threshold = 1023 * 3 / 5;
const unsigned long grace_time = 180000;
void loop() {
    int aread = analogRead(A0);
    if(aread > threshold) last_good = millis();
    // unsigned difference works fine even on wraparound 
    if(millis() - last_good > grace_time) {
        Serial.println("8");
        last_good = millis();
    } 
}
```